# RightToLeft ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, right-to-left

How can i make a `ViewPager` Right-to-Left?
Not just sliding from opposite side but everything become RTL!

For example `getPageWidth()` should make `ViewPager` like this:
[image]

Comment: 0
down vote
Reverse the fragment list.  setCurrentItem(fragmentList.size() - 1);

This will set current item to be the last item of the list, actually the 0th item (in the original list) of the list will be the last one in the reversed.

Comment: Yes i know this dude but what about reducing `pageWidth() `??

Comment: Look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071342/how-to-create-rtl-viewpager/37103408#37103408
This should work for you.